# Virtual (fake) primary monitor in Windows 10?

Tags: virtualization, ui-testing, gui-testing

I have a bunch of automated UI tests that currently require a physical monitor to run. Can I somehow create a virtual monitor in Windows 10 that functions like a real monitor to the OS? I want to run the UI tests in a remote cloud environment without screens.

I think I heard sometime that VR-development (Virtual Reality) have had similar problems in that VR also need a physical monitor attached (except the VR-headset) and that this was perhaps solved by Nvidia/Intel? with a fake monitor driver or similar? Or was it virtual desktops in VR? I can't find the source for any of this anymore...

Comment: By default many VM platforms do add one (and can up to 8) virtual display to the guest machine, that is acting as actual display -> no need to fake it inside of guest OS. What VM platform are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the Spacedesk utility:
https://spacedesk.net/

Spacedesk server part is installed on your PC.
The client part (viewer) will also be required - any device on Android/Windows in same LAN segment.

Small hack:
You can also install Windows Client on Spacedesk server PC and manually assign client IP from another subnet. As a result, you will assume real Windows fake display )...